# opencv4nodejs how to calculate the blur degree with variance of laplacian

Tags: python, node.js, opencv

I have a code:

```js
const cv = require('opencv4nodejs');

let text = "";

let image = cv.imread('./images/focused.jpg');
let gray = image.cvtColor(cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
let fm = image.laplacian(cv.CV_64F);
cv.imwrite('./images/new_very_blured.jpg', gray);

console.log(image);
console.log(fm);
console.log(fm.step / image.step);
```

And picture, which i saved is the black square, but its isn't what i expected.
I read an article about calculating the blur degrees and there:

```
cv2.Laplacian(image, cv2.CV_64F).var() // Python function
```

This article - https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/

But i using nodejs and in nodejs this function isn't exists, so i try to use other function, but it work doesn't as in Python. Please help me, how i need to edit my code to do it works. In the console i need to get a percent from 1 to 100, which will show me the blur degree.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. why you are asking me that?

Comment: you can try `var meanstddev = mat.meanStdDev();` which is what `var()` function does. It won't give you a percent value though (it doesn't give percent values in the article you linked either). You will have troubles getting percent values unless you take something as a reference.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. It doesn't work. Do you have anouther ideas? This is what i get in the console http://prntscr.com/l2x0gd

Comment: Looks like you calculated meanStdDev of your bgr image while as the article says - you need to calculate meanStdDev of gray image.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. This is my code : http://prntscr.com/l2x308 and i get the same result in console

Comment: @DmitriiZ. Are you there?

Comment: Than you got the result you wanted. Just take stddev's first pixel and multiply it by 2. Something like `var blurValue = meanstddev.stddev.at(0, 0) * meanstddev.stddev.at(0, 0)`. Not sure how to write it correctly in nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is complete solution:

```
//image : orirginal image
let gray = new cv.Mat();
let laplacian_mat = new cv.Mat();

cv.cvtColor(image, gray, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

cv.Laplacian(gray, laplacian_mat, cv.CV_64F, 1, 1, 0, cv.BORDER_DEFAULT);

// cv.imshow("canvasOutput", laplacian_mat);

let myMean = new cv.Mat(1, 4, cv.CV_64F);
let myStddev = new cv.Mat(1, 4, cv.CV_64F);
cv.meanStdDev(laplacian_mat, myMean, myStddev);

let sharpness = myStddev.doubleAt(0, 0);

console.log(sharpness * sharpness);


gray.delete();
laplacian_mat.delete();
myMean.delete();
myStddev.delete();
```