# How to calculate Laplacian Variance in OpenCV js?

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing

I am try to implement Blur detection using OpenCV but I cannot find any equivalent for the below statement in OpenCV js :
`cv2.Laplacian(image, cv2.CV_64F).var()`

Is there any other way to calculate variance ?

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate variance by getting the *Standard Deviation* of the Laplacian Mat and then **squaring** it. OpenCV has a function to calculate the standard deviation .

```
cv.meanStdDev(srcMat, mean, standardDeviationMat)
```

In the code below you can check how it's done. I'm reading the image from an [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object, then changing it to gray scale and finally calculating the *Laplacian Variance*:

```
const cvImage = cv.matFromImageData(imageData);
const grayImage = new cv.Mat();
const laplacianMat = new cv.Mat();

cv.cvtColor(cvImage, grayImage, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 0);
cv.Laplacian(grayImage, laplacianMat, cv.CV_64F);

const mean = new cv.Mat(1, 4, cv.CV_64F);
const standardDeviationMat = new cv.Mat(1, 4, cv.CV_64F);

cv.meanStdDev(laplacianMat, mean, standardDeviationMat);

const standardDeviation = standardDeviationMat.doubleAt(0, 0);
const laplacianVar = standardDeviation * standardDeviation;
```

There is a similar answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69408484/8820819), but using the package [*opencv4nodejs*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv4nodejs) instead of [*opencv.js*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv.js?activeTab=readme).

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty stumped on this as well. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/opencv-js-laplacian-image-blur-detection-t33863) is a link to a code sandbox if you want to play around with a working example. I have been using this with opencv.js 4.x.

Here is a code snippet for quick copy and paste:

```
const mean = (array = []) =>
  array.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0) / array.length;

const variance = (array = []) => {
  const m = mean(array);
  return array.reduce((acc, el) => acc + Math.pow(el - m, 2), 0) / array.length;
}

const processVideo = () => {
  let src = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
  let gray_src = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC1);
  let lap_gray = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC1);
  let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);
  const FPS = 15;

  let begin = Date.now();

  // start processing cap -> src
  cap.read(src); 

  // process src -> dst
  cv.cvtColor(src, gray_src, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
  cv.Laplacian(gray_src, lap_gray, -1);

  // this is the fm value in the original post
  const focusMeasure = Math.floor(variance(lap_gray.data));
  // console.log(fm); // uncomment to see; it will spam the console
  
  // write dst to canvas
  cv.imshow("canvasOutput", lap_gray);

  // schedule the next one.
  let delay = 1000 / FPS - (Date.now() - begin);
  setTimeout(processVideo, delay);
}
```